# Dynamic CSS class for MVC TextBoxFor & PasswordFor

Tags: c#, css, .net, model-view-controller

I have the following code that works well in displaying the CSS style for the log in text boxes I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id = "j_username", @class = "active_text_box", placeholder="UserName"})
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "j_password", @class = "active_text_box", placeholder = "Password" })
```

However, I want to apply the CSS class call "inactive_text_box" to these text field when they are not focused by the mouse.

Is there a built in property for this?

Comment: For purely visual effect -- add a new css rule `.active_text_box:focus { }` and leave your Razor code alone. If you need to add this class for other reasons then you'll need to use javascript events.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built-in property, but you could easily do this with jQuery's .hover() or .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() events.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Josh & Jasen for your answers.

I really like Jasen's recommendation(.active_text_box:focus { }) because it is very clean and require no scripting on the Razor view as pointed out.  Below is what I did in case someone will find this useful.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id = "j_username",@class = "login_fields", placeholder = "UserName" })
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "j_password", @class = "login_fields", placeholder = "Password" })
```

CSS Codes:

```
.login_fields:focus { 
color:#60b7c0;
border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
font-family: Arial;
font-size:16px ;
font-weight: bold;
height: 48px ;
line-height:48px ;
width: 500px ;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;

}

.login_fields {
color:#7d7d7d;
border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
font-family: Arial;
font-size:16px ;
font-weight: bold;
height: 48px ;
line-height:48px ;
width: 500px ;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I thought you were talking about when the mouse hovers over the textboxes rather than just when they have focus, maybe because you mentioned the mouse. I agree that for focus just use CSS so Jasen's answer is best.